# `NoClassDefFoundError: android.databinding.DataBindingUtil` when running androidTest for fragment with data biding

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, kotlin, android-databinding

It concerns the following Android library project: https://github.com/RoRoche/kAndroidModular/tree/master/kAndroidModular/userrepos

I try to run the following unit test: https://github.com/RoRoche/kAndroidModular/blob/master/kAndroidModular/userrepos/src/androidTest/java/fr/guddy/kandroidmodular/userrepos/UserReposFragmentTest.kt

Technical stack:

- MVVM architecture with [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) and [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)
- isolated fragment testing thanks to [Fragment Test Rule](https://github.com/21Buttons/FragmentTestRule)
- multidex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add '`com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1`' your required instrumentation testing dependencies in your gradle file

**i.e.**

```
`dependencies {
    kaptAndroidTest 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'
}`
```